# Is it possible to add MythTV support to an Apple TV? (yes, I have hacked the Apple TV)

Tags: appletv, mythtv

I just set up a MythTV backend to replace my dying DirecTV DVR.  The Myth box is headless and so I am dependent on separate frontend boxes to actually watch my recorded shows.  I found a great MythTV frontend for Macs [here](http://www.thesniderpad.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=42), and that works just fine on my Mac Pro (desktop) and MacBook Pro, even over WiFi.  However, I would like to be able to watch my MythTV programming on my Apple TV as well.  (I only record SD, so the AppleTV should have enough procesing horsepower to decode that.)  I've hacked my Apple TV using [atvusb-creator](http://code.google.com/p/atvusb-creator/) and so I have Boxee and XBMC on it; however, as far as I can tell, neither of these programs support the ".nuv" file format that MythTV records to.  I could use MythTV's transcode tools to turn these into standard H.264 or XviD or whatever; however I'd prefer it if I didn't have to do that intermediate step.  Is it possible to run the existing Mac OS X Myth frontend on the Apple TV?  (If I understand it right, the Apple TV is basically a Mac with a custom front-end running instead of the standard Finder/Dock/etc.)  If so, how would I go about doing this, and adding a "Run the MythFrontend" menu item to the Apple TV's menu structure?  I'm unfamiliar with the specifics of hacking the Apple TV; however, I do know my way around the command line, and am familiar with SSH, SFTP, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Installing_MythFrontend_on_an_AppleTV